# Creating a "circular" concept map

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I want to know how to create a circular concept map (see the picture below) using TikZ, I know how to create linear concept maps or flowcharts, but I have no idea on how to do this. I haven't seen similar questions and I have tried many things, but it seems this is too much for me.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Many users here can draw this but only a tiny fraction of them is keen on typing in the texts so please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

I find it somewhat disturbing that you dump all efforts on those who may be willing to help. For my part, I am not willing to punch in texts from a screen shot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,font=\large\bfseries,
ln/.style={font=\itshape\small,align=center}]
 \node[name=T,shape=ellipse split,draw] 
    {text\nodepart[font=\normalsize]{lower}
     \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\,}l@{}}
      \textbullet & pffft pffft pffft\\
      \textbullet & pffft pffft pffft\\
     \end{tabular}};
 \node[name=L,shape=rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw,below left=of T] 
  {text\nodepart[font=\normalsize]{two}
       \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\,}l@{}}
      \textbullet & pffft pffft pffft\\
      \textbullet & pffft pffft pffft\\
     \end{tabular}};
 \node[name=R,shape=rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw,below right=of T] 
  {text\nodepart[font=\normalsize]{two}
       \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\,}l@{}}
      \textbullet & pffft pffft pffft\\
      \textbullet & pffft pffft pffft\\
     \end{tabular}};
 \node[name=B,shape=ellipse split,draw,below right=of L] 
  {text\nodepart[font=\normalsize]{lower}
       \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\,}l@{}}
      \textbullet & pffft pffft pffft\\
      \textbullet & pffft pffft pffft\\
     \end{tabular}};
 \draw[-latex] (L.70) |- node[pos=0.75,below,ln]{pfffft\\ pffft}(T.200);
 \draw[-latex] (T.160) -| node[pos=0.25,above,ln]{pfffft}(L.110);
 \draw[-latex] (L.-110) |- node[pos=0.75,below,ln]{pfffft\\ pffft}(B.200);
 \draw[-latex] (B.160) -| node[pos=0.25,above,ln]{pfffft}(L.-70);
 \draw[-latex] (R.110) |- node[pos=0.75,below,ln]{pfffft\\ pffft}(T.-20);
 \draw[-latex] (T.20) -| node[pos=0.25,above,ln]{pfffft}(R.70);
 \draw[-latex] (R.-70) |- node[pos=0.75,below,ln]{pfffft\\ pffft}(B.-20);
 \draw[-latex] (B.20) -| node[pos=0.25,above,ln]{pfffft}(R.-110);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]